# How do you mark an entire file as deprecated in Python?

Tags: python, deprecated

I am reviewing a .py file with no classes, just a list of functions.  There is a newer version of this same file which is now used instead of the old file.

I know to mark class or function as deprecated, one can do `from warnings import deprecated` and then for the decorated function or class use `deprecated("Do not use this")`

There is not a 1-1 correspondence, so marking all the functions as deprecated individually seems weird.  I could wrap the code in a class, deprecate this newly created class, and be done with it.  However, it would be more natural to have a single annotation at the top of the page saying the entire contents of the file are to be ignored.

I could also create a new package, say deprecated, and move it there, but I would rather it keep the code in its original location.

So is there a pythonic way to mark an entire file as deprecated?

Comment: `deprecated` doesn't actually exist yet; it's slated for release in Python 3.13.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could raise a DeprecationWarning at the top of the file. So it is issued whenever it is imported.